# Scoped Model is returning an empty list Widget when used with ScopedDecendentModel along with custom Model

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have been using the scoped class but it always fails to return the specific List of my custom Model class which in turn displays my place holder. Moreover Scoped Model doesn't work everywhere.i.e. It works only at some specific places.

I renamed all the package imports to " import:'packages:...' " .
I also declared Scoped Model before using ScopedModelDecendant which was able to render some of the widgets but no List was returned and updated.

This is just a snippet of the code where I have used scoped Model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_course/widgets/ty/products/product_card.dart'

  import 'package:flutter_course/scoped_models/products.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_course/models/product.dart';

  import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

  class Products extends StatelessWidget {

    Widget _buildProductList(List<Product> products, BuildContext context) {
      Widget productCards;
      if (products.length > 0) {
        productCards = ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ProductCard(products[index], index, context);
          },
          itemCount: products.length,
        );
      } else {
        productCards = Container(child: Text('List is empty  bro!'));
      }
      print('product card just before returning main page list');
      return productCards;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      print('[Products Widget] build()');

    return ScopedModel<ProductsModel>(model: ProductsModel(),child: ScopedModelDescendant(builder: (BuildContext context,Widget child,ProductsModel model){
      print('building list '+model.products.toString());
      return  _buildProductList(model.products, context);
    }),);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you example you are Creating a new scoped model throw this code

```
 return ScopedModel<ProductsModel>(model: ProductsModel(),child: ScopedModelDescendant(builder: (BuildContext context,Widget child,ProductsModel model){
  print('building list '+model.products.toString());
  return  _buildProductList(model.products, context);
}),);
}
```

so i believe you are not using the main scoped model you declared before   so i suggest if you already declared a **ScopedModel** before the code should be like that in order that you  dont override the main scoped model

```
return  ScopedModelDescendant(builder: (BuildContext context,Widget child,ProductsModel model){
      print('building list '+model.products.toString());
      return  _buildProductList(model.products, context);
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  And yes I was missing the Scope Model in the main.dart file 
And then I just used the ScopedModelDecendant